# Android linked in sdk integration

Tags: android

I am integrating login via Linkedin and successfully created clientId & clientsecret in android. I have generated hokey, but I don't know where I have to paste the app packagename & generated hash key in Linkedin developer console. Kindly anyone guide me to continue the further process on it. I am totally struck. Where I can get the access token for the authorization process.[here i attached the linked in console, where i can find the mobile tab option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ34T.png)

Answer (score 0):

Login in your linked in & register your app with package & hash key in your "My Apps" Dashboard. (This is same like Facebook)

User this link to get login in LinkedIn Developer Console.
https://www.linkedin.com/developers/login

Answer (score 0):

Please find steps below for LinkedIn integration in Android.

1. Create Application

   - To Integrate LinkedIn in your mobile application, you need to create a new 
     application using LinkedIn Developer’s Account
   - Create application from LinkedIn developer account 
     https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps
2. Set the Application Permission

   You have to set the Default Application Permissions and to do that you have to 
    select check box “r_basicprofile” and “r_emailaddress” and click on the “update” 
    button to set the permission.
3. Download Mobile LinkedIn SDK

   Go to https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk and download a Mobile SDK for 
     Android
4. Generate Hash Key

   - Generate a hash key and integrate your app with LinkedIn account
   - Go to https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps
   - Select your application name and click the Mobile tab
   - Add the package name and generated hash key in your LinkedIn Application.
   - This hash key will authenticate your mobile application.

[refer this link](https://www.solutionanalysts.com/blog/step-by-step-developers-guide-to-integrate-linkedin-with-an-android-application/)

Comment: In step 4 (Select your application name and click the Mobile tab) this option not available in https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps

Comment: I have included the screen shot of my application, where mobile tab is not present.kindly help me out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are following the old documentation. The documentation on [developer.linkedin.com](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth) is outdated and the official SDK for android is also deprecated. You need to refer to the latest documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin) or use an [unofficial sdk](https://github.com/shantanu-deshmukh/LinkedIn-SDK-Android) for the same.

The official documentation [vaguely states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api) that the access tp `r_basicprofile` permission is now restricted to some developers.

> The use of this API is restricted to those developers approved by
>   LinkedIn and subject to applicable data restrictions in their
>   agreements.

Other developers only have access to `r_liteprofile` permission which returns only the id, first name, last name and profile url for the user.

Also the new API returns weird JSON format containing special characters in key names. This makes it difficult to use dynamic JSON parsers or networking libraries like Retrofit.

To make it easier to implement Login with LinkedIn in android, I've created a lightweight [library](https://github.com/shantanu-deshmukh/LinkedIn-SDK-Android). If you prefer to do it on your own refer to the [official migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context).